# How to compare cell1 against cell 2 groups of 2 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a way to compare cells in blocks of two's. Need compare D2 against D3, D4 againt D5 ... D10 against D11.

If two individual cells like D2 or D3 equal "Business" or "Compliance", then return true.

If a block has identical values like "Business" in cells D6 & D7 or "Compliance" like in cell D10 & D11, then the code should return fail.

[image]

```
create table data
(
  ID int,
  [Col A]  nvarchar(10),
  [Col B]  nvarchar(10),
  [Col C] nvarchar(10)
);

insert into data (ID, [Col C]) values
(1, 'Business'),
(2, 'Compliance'),
(3, 'Compliance'),
(4, 'Business'),
(5, 'Business'),
(6, 'Business'),
(7, 'Compliance'),
(8, 'Business'),
(9,'Compliance'),
(10,'Compliance');

select d.ID,
       d.[Col C],
       case when ( d.[Col C] = coalesce(lag(d.[Col C]) over(order by d.ID), '')
               and d.[Col C] = coalesce(lead(d.[Col C]) over(order by d.ID), '') ) then 'FAIL'
            when d.[Col C] <> coalesce(lag(d.[Col C]) over(order by d.ID), '')     then 'Ok'
            when d.[Col C] <> coalesce(lead(d.[Col C]) over(order by d.ID), '')    then 'Ok'
       end as B
from data d
order by d.ID;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d4d4aca6c01d11378ce93a67fa44d56a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions to compare the rows in the group:

```
select d.*,
       (case when min(c) over (partition by (id - 1) / 2) = max(c) over (partition by (id - 1) / 2)
             then 'fail' else 'ok'
        end)
from data d
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=09cef3c30df0a600ca4af048ccf7dd2b) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  This assumes that `id` has no gaps.  If it does, you can use `row_number()` to calculate a sequence.

Comment: Is there a way to acomplish the same result by reading the nvarchar?

Comment: @user716255 . . . I don't know what you mean.  This does what you are asking for.

Comment: The code work. Just remember there are times where [Col C] will equal something other than "Business" and "Complinace". Need the code to return true  only when "Business" and "Compliance" are next to each other and false if say" Accouting" and "Business" are adjecent to each other.

Comment: @user716255 . . . Then you should ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Don't use the word "like" if you don't mean "like".

Comment: Wouldn't it work to use this grouping logic but check minimum against "Business" and maximum against "Compliance"?